# Why do I get these errors in VS when I use OGRE_NEW?

Tags: c++, ogre

I am trying to get more experienced with Ogre 3D and I am following the basic tutorials on the website. All the code samples compile just fine.

The first time I encountered an "error" was in [Basic Tutorial 3](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Basic+Tutorial+3).

The code line where Visual Studio says something is not right is

```
mTerrainGroup = OGRE_NEW Ogre::TerrainGroup(mSceneMgr, Ogre::Terrain::ALIGN_X_Z, 513, 12000.0f);
```

Visual Studio compiles this line but it shows an ugly red line beneath it and on mouse hover it says

> `#define OGRE_NEW new (__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__) Error: no instance of overloaded 'operator new' matches the argument list" or if I mouse hover over Ogre::TerrainGlobalOptions() it says "Error: expected a type specifier`

I searched on Google but couldn't find my answer. I got about a year C++ experience but that was mainly with the WinSock libary.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OGRE_NEW** is just an overload of the operator **new**. Try to replace **OGRE_NEW** by the normal operator **new**. If it compiles, there is a problem in the declaration of OGRE_NEW. Otherwise, just find the problem and uses again the OGRE_NEW operator.

Ps: if you use OGRE_NEW, you need to use OGRE_DELETE to remove your allocated object.